# Необходимо составить комбинации элементов из матрицы с условием их сопоставления с предыдущими элементами

Tags: python, python-3.x, комбинаторика

Задача:
есть матрица корреляции:

```
              A         B        C      ...      AD1  
  A       1.000000  0.554783  0.807248  ...  0.411838 
  B       0.554783  1.000000  0.268990  ...  0.779533
  C       0.807248  0.268990  1.000000  ...  0.074832
  ...       ....
  AD1    -0.050304  0.715818 -0.295941  ...  0.713958
```

её размер 400 элементов
нужно найти комбинацию из 7 элементов в диапазоне от -0.5 до 0.5 между каждым элементов в комбинации
к примеру я беру первую комбинацию A,B,C,D,E,F,G и если значение ['A']['B'] находится в диапазоне - то продолжить формировать комбинацию, если нет то перейти к следующему элементу ['A']['C'] и так до тех пор пока не будет получена комбинация из 7 элементов е примеру ['A']['D']['F']['D1']['AA1']['AB3']['AD1']
и далее перейти к следующему элементу в матрице ( то есть к B) и так же рассчитать для нее комбинации с теми же условиями

Вот код обычной функции itertools.combinations

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: Можно увидеть ваш код? Что конкретно не получилось?

Comment: проблема в том что я не могу написать этот код, для анализа написания, я использовал обычную функцию itertools.combinations но она перебирает от обратного, у меня не получается декомпозировать функцию на линейные логические подчасти (код пишу в python, входная матрица pandas.DataFrame)

Comment: Наличие кода в вопросе (даже нерабочего) снижает вероятность закрытия вопроса и повышает вероятность ответа

Comment: Вы ограничены в инструментах? Pandas, например, применять допустимо?

Comment: И вопрос к постановке задачи: сочетания нужно искать только в строках или вообще в массиве? если в строках, то нужно найти хотя бы одну комбинацию или все? Или вообще одну комбинацию во всем массиве достаточно? А комбинация - это 7 чисел в указанном диапазоне?

Comment: Pandas я и использую в качестве матрицы корреляции. Нужно найти все сочитания из 7 элементов в матрице при условии что каждый элемент коррелирует друг с другом в диапазоне -0.5 до 0.5 и при этом не перебирать факторил как это указано в функции в примере, а использовать сокращение расчета, с учетом того что предыдущие элементы внутри уже формирующейся комбинации подходят под условие в диапозоне -0.5 до 0.5 с текущим перебираемым элементом

Comment: Комбинация это названия элементов матрицы а не числа

Comment: Сочитания нужно искать во всем массиве чтобы к примеру получить те сочитания что есть с элементом А, так и без него, к примеру начиная с элемента В

Comment: Мне не хватает мощностей чтобы перебрать комбинацию из 7 элементов для 410, по этому решил что можно исключить из расчета формирования комбинации элементы заведомо не подходящие друг другу в этом диапазоне и не считать от обратного как это указано в коде в примере

Comment: Из матрицы извлеките граф, как набор компонент связности. Затем придётся делать поиск: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: Небольшое уточнение: когда каждый выбранный элемент связан друг с другом - это про клики (полносвязные подграфы), а не про пути все-таки.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Думаю убрать из матрицы значения вне диапазона и построить поверх этой матрицы граф, а после найти клики внутри через  networkx